# Probability of 2 picked numbers in an interval the smallest being bigger or equal to 80

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The problem is based on picking 2 people of 100.All 100 have badges with their numbers.Whats the probability of those 2 the smallest being bigger or equal to 80?

I believe its 20C2/100C2 is this right?

Answer (score 0):

In your answer the denominator represents the number of ways to pick the two people out of $100$. The numerator should represents the number of ways to pick two people from the range $80$ to $100$ inclusive (there are $100-80+1=21$ numbers in this range). Hence the answer is 
$$
{\binom{21}{2}}\biggr/{\binom{100}{2}}
$$

Comment: The adding of the 1 is because we're trying to find the smallest?